# JDBC JOINing multiple child tables to a parent table, how can i know from which table is the resulting row?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, left-join

Lets suppose i have 3 tables one is parent others are child

```
| Resource   |
______________
| id          |
| name        |
|author       |
_______________


|  Movie      |
_______________
|id
|lenght
|main actor
________________


| Book           |
__________________
|id
|number of pages  |
|Pubblisher       |
___________________
```

now what i want to do is joining the three tables together start a rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql)
to retrieve all the data so that the sql String i pass might be

```
sql= "SELECT * FROM Resource
LEFT JOIN Movie
LEFT JOIN BOOK
USING(id)
```

then

```
while(rs.next())
{
//creating different objects with the data base on if its a movie or a book
..
}
```

how can i know from the join i made from which table the resulting row is from (movie or book) without using checks on attributes like

```
if(rs.getString("pubblisher").equals(NULL))
//creation of a movie
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you can't. Your results don't come from a specific table anymore.

Comment: i want to create Movie objects or Book objects, which exist in my java program, based on the data i retrieve from this 3 table join. And i want to know for each row the resultset point if it is a book or a movie, without checking if attributes are null to do so. thank you

Comment: @FLM995 if you want to do it without checking for null attributes (preferably in the query, as in GMB's answer), you're going to have to make two queries.

Comment: @Kayaman is in your opinion more expensive to do multiple two table joins than doing one multiple tables join?

Comment: @FLM995 I just provided you with the alternative since you said you don't **want** to check the attributes. If you're actually matching authors to books and movies, performance doesn't matter. If you're working with real amounts of data, you can performance test both approaches.

Comment: @Kayaman i think i will try this approach, your answers were very useful. thank you very much sir :)

Answer (score 4):

Don't use `SELECT *`. Instead, you should list the columns you want your query to return; and you can use a `CASE` expression to implement the logic that checks from which column values were returned:

```
select 
    r.id resource_id,
    r.name resource_name,
    r.author resource_author,
    m.length movie_length,
    m.main_actor movie_main_actor,
    b.number_of_pages book_number_of_pages,
    b.publisher book_publisher,
    case
        when m.id is not null then 'movie'
        when b.id is not null then 'book'
        else 'none'
    end src
from resource r
left join movie m on m.id = r.id
left join book b on b.id = r.id
```

Here column `src` will contain either `movie`, `book`, or `none`, depending on which `left join` did succeed. If it is possible that both `left join`s would succceed (which does not seem likely given your set-up), then you can adapt the logic:

```
    case
        when m.id is not null and b.id is not null then 'both'
        when m.id is not null then 'movie'
        when b.id is not null then 'book'
        else 'none'
    end src
```

Comment: While this is correct, this just moves the "using checks on attributes" (that OP wants to avoid) from the code to the sql statement.

Comment: @f1sh: sure, but how could we do differently?

Comment: done that i have to do something like this:
while(rs.next()){
if(rs.getString("src").equals("movie"))
   { //creation of a movie with the rest of the data
   }
   if(rs.getString("src").equals("book"))
   { //creation of a book with the rest of the data
   }

Comment: @MauricePerry it doesn't solve the underlying issue: you don't know which table the data came from. This answer evaluates column values to determine that. But you might as well evaluate these attributes in the java code then, which OP specifically tries to avoid.

Comment: @f1sh I don't get it. I don't get why he doesn't want to do the test in the Java code either.